# Cannot set author field using powershell in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

The Author field (created by) is not updating via the powershell script.  The Editor and created and modified date fields are all updating as expected.  i am pulling the list data off of a CSV.  I get no errors when attempting to write to the Author field, even when I manually add junk data into the script replacing the getUser call.  The getUser call is a separate function, which works fine with the Editor field,

Any ideas?

Here's a snippet of script:

```
foreach($row in $tblData){
  item.File.Name.Length -gt 0){
    if($row."FileName" -eq $item.File.Name){
      write-host 'file ' $item.File.Name
      $fileCount++
      try{
          write-host 'updating info for ' $item.File.Name
          $item["Author"] = getUser($row."CreatedBy")
          $item["Editor"] = getUser($row."ModifiedBy")
          $item["Created"] = [DateTime]$row."CreatedAt"
          $item["Modified"] = [DateTime]$row."ModifiedAt"
          $item.Update()
          $Context.Load($item)
          $Context.ExecuteQuery()
      }
      catch [System.Exception] 
      { 
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
      }   
   }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks guys.  Some more information:

I am working on this as part of a migration.  The script appears to set the Author field at first pass with a brand new document library.  However, the Author field is then reset to me after a minute or so.  I had moved the documents over with the SP Sync functionality - copying/pasting the documents locally and syncing with the new SP location, then turning off SP offline mode for the site collection.  It makes a bit of sense that the fields would reset to the synced documents, but it only ever happens on the Author field - all other fields work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using below script , Please make sure that correct user object is assigned to the Author field:

if its works perfect with Editor filed then the user object assigned wrongly to the Author field , try adding a hard coded user object as below and check the same.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0 
#specify new user - login name 
$newuser = "Domain\user" 
#specify the web URL 
$site = get-SPWeb http://vm353/pwa/ProjectBICenter 
#specify the list name 
$list = $site.Lists["Test"] 
$listitems = $list.Items 
$user = get-SPuser -Web $site -Identity $newuser 
#loop through each list item and update 
foreach ($listitem in $listitems) 
{ 

    $listitem["Author"] = $user 
    $listitem["Editor"] = $user        
    $listitem.Update() 
    write-host $listitem["Name"] "has been updated. The author and editor has been set to $user" 

} 
$site.Update(); 
$site.Dispose();
```

Comment: your script will not work because environment is **SharePoint Online**

Comment: Ok , will have a look over it